# Ruby: Printing system output in real time?

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a ruby rake task that calls a bash script via:

```
Open3.popen('/path/file_converter.sh', file_list, output_format)
```

That bash script outputs logs to the command line as it processes (which takes from 30 secs to 5 hours)

When I call the rake task, the output from bash is returned to the command line, but only as one large message after the entire script has run. Anyone know of a way to pipe command line output direct to ruby output as it occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) you should be able to use the output stream given in the block:

```
Open3.popen3('/path/file_converter.sh', file_list, output_format) do |_,out,_,_|
  out.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the output into a file. And run the process in the background creating a new thread. After it you can parse the file.

```
class FileConverter
  def initialize
    @output_file = '/tmp/something.txt'
    output_format = 'foo'
    file_list = 'bar foo something'
    @child = Thread.new do
      `/path/file_converter.sh #{file_list} #{output_format} 2>&1 >#{@output_file}`
    end
  end

  def data
    File.readlines(@output_file)
  end

  def parse
    while @child.alive?
      # parse data # TODO: need to implement real parsing
      sleep 0.5
    end
  end
end

fc = FileConverter.new
fc.parse
```